# How to filter the data in a table according to a value selected from the dropdown list in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have table containing data such as name,age,address,status etc. In the status column, it contains values like Item Picked or Item Not Picked. Table is Shown below :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sreeraj</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>KErala</td>
    <td>Item Picked</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sreenivasan</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>KErala</td>
    <td>Item Not Picked</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jincy</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>KErala</td>
    <td>Item Picked</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the table above, I want to filter all the data according to status column ie. Item Picked and Item Not Picked.If I am selecting the value from the dropdown as Item Picked , then in the table it should show the item picked items only.

The select box is shown below :

```
<select name="option" class="optionn" id="items">
   <option value="">All</option>
   <option value="Item Picked">Item Picked</option>
   <option value="Item Not Picked">Item Not Picked</option>
</select>
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to do this ?

Comment: Before table print you have any Data formatted in JSON or it just an static table here.?

Comment: You tagged this as php, where does php come into it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo-class selector to select `tr`  which contains specific text.

```
// bind change event handler
$('#items').change(function() {
  // get all tr which contains the selected value in the last td
  // and show them 
  var $tr = $('#table tr:has(td:last-child:contains(' + this.value + '))').show();
  // get all tr except first and  the content matched tr
  $('#table tr:not(:first-child)').not($tr).hide();
})
```

```js
$('#items').change(function() {
  var $tr = $('#table tr:has(td:last-child:contains(' + this.value + '))').show();
  $('#table tr:not(:first-child)').not($tr).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>Sreeraj</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>KErala</td>
    <td>Item Picked</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>Sreenivasan</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>KErala</td>
    <td>Item Not Picked</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>Jincy</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>KErala</td>
    <td>Item Picked</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<select name="option" class="optionn" id="items">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="Item Picked">Item Picked</option>
  <option value="Item Not Picked">Item Not Picked</option>
</select>
```

---

In case you want exact match then use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method for exact text content match.

```
// bind change event handler
$('#items').change(function() {
  // get input option value
  var val = this.value.trim();
  //  filter out tr based on the select value
  var $tr = $('#table tr').filter(function() {
    // return true if value is empty or matched the contents
    return val == '' || $('td:last-child', this).text().trim() == val;
  }).show();      
  // get all tr except first and the content matched tr
  $('#table tr:not(:first-child)').not($tr).hide();
})
```

```js
$('#items').change(function() {
  var val = this.value.trim();
  var $tr = $('#table tr').filter(function() {
    return val == '' || $('td:last-child', this).text().trim() == val;
  }).show();
  $('#table tr:not(:first-child)').not($tr).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>Sreeraj</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>KErala</td>
    <td>Item Picked</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>Sreenivasan</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>KErala</td>
    <td>Item Not Picked</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>Jincy</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>KErala</td>
    <td>Item Picked</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<select name="option" class="optionn" id="items">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="Item Picked">Item Picked</option>
  <option value="Item Not Picked">Item Not Picked</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ss..the item picked and not picked for each row, I have displayed it in a dropdown box..Changing code according to that

Answer (score 0):

Hope below jquery scripting help you.
Don't forget to include JQuery script.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#items').on('change', function(){
        $("tr").show();
        if($('#items').val() =='Item Picked'){
            $("td:contains('Item Not Picked')").parent().hide();
        }
        if($('#items').val() =='Item Not Picked'){
            $("td:contains('Item Picked')").parent().hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```